# Add the results of RLE to the original data frame in R

Tags: r, apply, rle

I have a data frame containing dates and for each date the number of events that took place.  From this I add a field telling me if the number of events was above average or not.

| Date | Events | Above Average |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | 7 | 0 |
| 02/01 | 8 | 1 |
| 03/01 | 8 | 1 |
| 04/01 | 6 | 0 |
| 05/01 | 8 | 1 |
| 06/01 | 9 | 1 |
| 07/01 | 4 | 0 |
| 08/01 | 7 | 0 |

From this, if I perform an RLE I get

| Count | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 2 | TRUE |
| 1 | FALSE |
| 2 | TRUE |
| 2 | FALSE |

How can I use this information to add an addition field as below to my original data frame:

| Date | Events | Above Average | Run Above Av |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/01 | 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 03/01 | 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 04/01 | 6 | 0 | 0 |
| 05/01 | 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 06/01 | 9 | 1 | 2 |
| 07/01 | 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 08/01 | 7 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Can you show us the code which produced the rle table? And what exactly does "Run Above Av" represent?

Comment: Hi Andrew, just a question. Why do you create a criteria for a column that is already the information/criteria? I mean `Above average` has the same information as `Run Above Av`.

Comment: @user2974951 - the code is simple rle(df$Events)
Run Above Av - if the current row is above average, it gives the number of contiguous rows that are above average and of which the current row is a member (hope that makes sense)

Comment: @Stephan Above average and Run Above Av will not be the same.  If the current row is part of a contiguous range of rows that are all above average, Run Above Av will give the number of contiguous rows.  I will be using this field to filter to just rows which are part of runs of 7 or more all above average in order to create an SPC Chart.

Comment: So there will be occasions that eg event 8 in your example will have a 0 assigend to above average on eg 9/1 or whatever?

Comment: Something does not add up, that code does not produce your intermediate table, for one Value column has booleans when it should have events integers, second it has 3 sequences of length 2 while your original table has only 1 such sequence?

Comment: @user2974951 You are correct, the code for the rle should have been rle(df$Events > Mean)

The original table did indeed have three sequences of length 2, it's just that one of them was a sequence of below averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for the rle lengths, each repeated by itself, then multiplied by the sign of the `Above Average` column

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(`Run Above Av` = rep(rle(`Above Average`)$lengths,
            times = rle(`Above Average`)$lengths) * sign(`Above Average`))
#>    Date Events Above Average Run Above Av
#> 1 01/01      7             0            0
#> 2 02/01      8             1            2
#> 3 03/01      8             1            2
#> 4 04/01      6             0            0
#> 5 05/01      8             1            2
#> 6 06/01      9             1            2
#> 7 07/01      4             0            0
#> 8 08/01      7             0            0
```

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(Date = c("01/01", "02/01", "03/01", "04/01", "05/01", 
"06/01", "07/01", "08/01"), Events = c(7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 
4L, 7L), `Above Average` = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>